# Triggering an action based on its custom shortcut

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt5, action, hotkeys

Suppose I have some action to happen. For that I can create a `QAction` object and connect its `triggered()` signal to the slot that executes the desired function. Also, I can have a shortcut associated with the action; by changing the shortcut I'll be able to execute the same action with that shortcut.

My problem now is that the "shortcut" I wanna set to the action, contains also a mouse button press (and mouse events cannot be assigned to action shortcuts); say I want `Shift+Left mouse button`. Maybe this sounds a little bit harsh but bear with me.

What do I need? Well, I have a button, and an action (say "execute a script"). I want the script to execute when `Shift+Left click` is clicked, and I want this "shortcut" to be customized, i.e. the user should be able to change to shortcut to, say `Ctrl+Left click` (from some GUI element, e.g. button text), and now `Ctrl+Left click` should execute the script.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't know how. but sounds like a horrible UI design.

Comment: @GeneCode I don't know enough about OP's app to vote for or against your statement...

Comment: A button is for a single left click. Any other anomaly is a bad UI design. It is not readily understandable from user point of view. But this is out of topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I as a user would expect an action triggered by a mouse button to be position dependent. If so, the following gets a bit simpler.

Qt doesn't have an option to specify such a shortcut.

You can roll your own by reacting to mouse events:

- Maybe you have an event handler `mousePressEvent()`,
- or a generic `eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *evt)`,
- or utilize `QApplication::notify`

Whichever, at some place you need to catch a `QMouseEvent *mouseEvt`.

Choose the widget (or qApp) that is as outmost as needed.

There, compare `mouseEvt->button()` and `mouseEvt->modifiers()` to your list of actions and trigger the selected action. When the user chooses another trigger method, adjust your list of actions.

---

Let's put this to practice:

```
class MainWindow : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QMap<QPair<Qt::MouseButton, Qt::KeyboardModifiers>, QAction*> mapMouseShortcuts;
    QAction *pLaunchScript;

    MainWindow() : QWidget() {
        mapMouseShortcuts.insert(qMakePair(Qt::LeftButton, Qt::ControlModifier), pLaunchScript);
    }

    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *me) {
        QAction *action = mapMouseShortcuts.value(qMakePair(me->button(), me->modifiers()), Q_NULLPTR);
        if(action != Q_NULLPTR) {
            action->trigger();
            me->accept(); // optional
        }
        // optional:
        if(!me->isAccepted()) {
            QWidget::mousePressEvent(me);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: How should I compare `mouseEvt->button()` and `mouseEvt->modifiers()` to the list of actions?

Comment: thanks, will try. also I have question - one of the bindings is Alt + left mouse button. But on Linux that combination is caught by the window manager and doesn't reach my widget. How can I actually catch that event in `mousePressEvent()`?

Comment: If "that combination is caught by the window manager and doesn't reach my widget" Qt can't know about it. Either disable the shortcut in your window manager or use a (platform-dependent) method to get your mouse states. (Search for 'linux mouse hook') But before you do that, you should seriously consider if your approach is correct. After all, if you distribute your app and if your window system has some shortcut, so do those on other PCs. Don't break system user interaction!

Comment: okay, by the way I used Ctrl+Alt+click instead. Can that be a problem?